# How do I get more Tour Centers?

Tags: world-cruise-story

I only have knew tour center and would love to have more so I can explore places faster. How do I get additional ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Tour Center is all you get, I'm afraid.  There's no way to explore faster, other than to surround your single Center with nice stuff.  The higher the attraction value, the more satisfaction you'll get from your tour guests, and that's what determines how fast you explore a location.

Comment: Boo. I was hoping to get more. I am so greedy. :p